# How to normalize a list of int values

Tags: c#, .net

I have a list of int values:

> `List<int> histogram;`

How do I normalize all values so that the max value in the list is always 100?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Iterate though, find the maximum value (call it `MAXVAL`), then iterate through once more and multiply every value in the list by `(100/MAXVAL)`.

```
var ratio = 100.0 / list.Max();
var normalizedList = list.Select(i => i * ratio).ToList();
```

Comment: oh, and the max value can be 0, so you have 100/0.

Comment: Yes, that boundary case should probably be checked for - though there's no real good way to 'normalize' a list which is all zero.

Comment: @Dav: Just because the max is zero does not mean that every entry in the list is zero.

Comment: Correct, Jason, but the solution I had given would only work for non-negative lists anyways. For lists that can include negative values, there's still a boundary case, it simply becomes when min == max instead of when max == 0.

Answer (score 9):

If you have a list of strictly positive numbers, then Dav's answer will suit you fine.

If the list can be any numbers at all, then you need to also normalise to a lowerbound.

Assuming an upper bound of 100 and a lower bound of 0, you'll want something like this ...

```
var max = list.Max();
var min = list.Min();
var range = (double)(max - min);
var normalised 
    = list.Select( i => 100 * (i - min)/range)
        .ToList();
```

Handling the case where `min == max` is left as an exercise for the reader ...

Answer (score 9):

To normalize a set of numbers that may contain negative values,
and to define the normalized scale's range:

```c#
List<int> list = new List<int>{-5,-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4,5};
double scaleMin = -1; //the normalized minimum desired
double scaleMax = 1; //the normalized maximum desired

double valueMax = list.Max();
double valueMin = list.Min();
double valueRange = valueMax - valueMin;
double scaleRange = scaleMax - scaleMin;

IEnumerable<double> normalized = 
    list.Select (i =>
        ((scaleRange * (i - valueMin))
            / valueRange)
        + scaleMin);
```