# How to normalize Minimum bounded rectangles into a square [10000][10000]?

Tags: floating-point, spatial, rectangles, mbr

I have a spatial data set downloaded from http://www.rtreeportal.org/

MBR's are a rectangle with value like:

506364.3125 4583290.0 508388.09375 4584786.0  representing(x_low,y_low,x_high,y_high) of the rectangle.

As you can see all the locations are co-ordinated by large float values. And there are almost 20000+ rectangles in the space.

I want to generate the whole space into a space with area [10000][10000]

the lowest of all x will become 0

the highest of all x will become 10000

the lowest of all y will become 0

the highest of all y will become 10000

All the other x and y co-ordinates will be changed accordingly.How to do it? What will be the logic?

Answer (score 0):

I misunderstood the concept of normalizing data point. Got an answer from 
[normalizing a list of doubles to range -1 to 1 or 0 - 255](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10376600/normalizing-a-list-of-doubles-to-range-1-to-1-or-0-255)