# Normalize a vector with one fixed value

Tags: c#

I have this problem where I want to keep a list of values and normalize them so that the sum of all values is 1.

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1226587/363224), but there is one difference. I would like to have 1 value that is fixed. Because, there are 4 GUI sliders and I drag one. The other 3 should update accordingly so that the total sum is 1.

```
// Let's keep 0.6 fixed and try to normalize the rest
List<float> categories = new List<float>() { 0.6f,0.3f,0.25f,0.25f };

// find the max value of the rest of the values that is not the fixed number
float maxval = categories.Where(s => s != 0.6f).Max();

if (maxval != 0) // check if not all other 
{
    // calculate the ratio
    float ratio = (1 - 0.6f) / maxval;

    foreach (float s in categories)
    {
        if (s != 0.6f)
        {
            s *= ratio;
        }
    }
}
else // all values are 0, so just add the rest value
{
    // do something else that is correct
}
```

Unfortunately this example will return:

```
{ 0.6f, 0.4f, 0.33f, 0.33f } => sum is 1.66f
```

And there is something that I'm misunderstanding. Can someone give me a clue on how to get the rest of the values normalized to the rest sum (0.4f) so that the total sum of all values is 1?

Comment: Don't replace your values during the drag operation, use a second set of values for display.  That way you can do all your calculations on the pre-drag values.  If you do calculations based on values computed during the drag, your rounding error will accumulate very rapidly.

Comment: When you got it working, can you please mark the question as answered? If its not working as expected, can you let us know whats going wrong?

Comment: @AntonRoth I'll be at the office on monday ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are calculating it wrongly.

If you have a 4 elements, and 1 of those is fixed, and the total sum needs to be 1, you would go like:

```
ratio = (1-fixedElement) / sumOfAllOtherElements;

EachNonFixedElement *= ratio;
```

You are calculating the ratio just with the max value, but you need to calculate it with the sum of all non-fixed elements.

Answer (score 0):

Among other problems, this loop doesn't do what you expect:

```
foreach (float s in categories) {
    if (s != 0.6f) {
        s *= ratio;
    }
}
```

`s` is a local copy of one of the values from `categories`.  You modify the copy, and then it goes out of scope and your new value disappears.  You never modified `categories`.

C# `foreach` cannot be used to modify a collection.

Furthermore, to avoid accumulating large rounding error, you should store to a new collection and not replace the values in `categories`, at least until the drag operation ends.

Comment: Thanks I know that. I am actually looping over my own class `GuiComponent`, but this was just for the sake of simplicity.