# Return number from 1 to 10 based on the number size

Tags: c#

Let's say I have some random numbers between 1 and 20 like this:

```
{3,7,14,8,17,6,12}
```

Now, I need to obtain a number between 1 and 10 for every number, based on the number size.

So for example the smaller number must return 1 and the greatest must return 10.

How can I achieve this?

EDIT

Here the solution that suits with some small changes, I found here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/7989299/16356535

```
List<int> list = new List<int> { 3, 7, 14, 8, 17, 6, 12 };
        int scaleMin = 10; //the normalized minimum desired
        int scaleMax = 1; //the normalized maximum desired

        int valueMax = list.Max();
        int valueMin = list.Min();
        int valueRange = valueMax - valueMin;
        int scaleRange = scaleMax - scaleMin;

        IEnumerable<int> normalized =
            list.Select(i =>
               ((scaleRange * (i - valueMin))
                   / valueRange)
               + scaleMin);
        
            Console.WriteLine(normalized);
```

Comment: You lost me at "*Now, I need to obtain a number between 1 and 10 for every number, based on the number size.*"

Comment: We expect you to try *something* first, then we can help you where you are stuck. Expected output (real output, not description) would help as well.

Comment: The term you are looking for is "normalize". Here for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1226587/how-to-normalize-a-list-of-int-values

Comment: It sounds like you need to sort the numbers, then return their index in the sorted list. But what about the case where you have some identical values?

Comment: @Klamsi thank you for suggesting. I will search normalize and trying something

Comment: @HansKeﬆing I need to calculate a workout intensity based on the number of reps. Less reps are more intense and more reps are less intense. Identical values can have the same intensity

Comment: @Gabriele Honestly, that's an assumption that I consider dangerously guessing. I can do 3 whimpy reps or 3 Schwarzenegger reps, I can do 30 whimpy reps or 30 Schwarzeneggers ... your assumption is based on what they _should_ be. - not really related to the problem, but I thought you should be aware of this.

Comment: @Fildor yes I know. My assumption is correct only if you bring every set to failure.

Comment: Something like this: https://dotnetfiddle.net/s93YQp?

Comment: FYI - you could have posted the edit as an answer to your own question, but since your answer is more or less from the different question, I am marking your question as duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

You almost have it.

```
List<int> list = new List<int> { 3, 7, 14, 8, 17, 6, 12 };
int scaleMin = 1; //the normalized minimum desired
int scaleMax = 10; //the normalized maximum desired

int valueMax = list.Max();
int valueMin = list.Min();
int valueRange = valueMax - valueMin;
int scaleRange = scaleMax - scaleMin;

IEnumerable<int> normalized =
  list.Select(i =>
    ((scaleRange * (i - valueMin)) / valueRange) + scaleMin);

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(',', normalized));
```